# magento ce 1.7 exclude previously displayed on product page while sorting random

Tags: php, magento, sorting, pagination

exclude previously displayed products while sorting random and navigating to next page

i m using

```
if($this->getCurrentOrder() != 'price'){
        if($this->getCurrentOrder() != 'created_at') {
            $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
        }else{
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
}else{
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
}
```

in toolbar.php to display random items in product page but the products keep repeating !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy @marius

You need to order the products by a 'seeded' random order and make sure the 'seed' is the same all through out the session.

Here is a possible approach. I haven't tested it, but I've used this kind of seeded random sorting for listing other entities.

```
if($this->getCurrentOrder() != 'price'){
    if($this->getCurrentOrder() != 'created_at') {
        //check if there is a seed in the session.
        $seed = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getListSeed();
        //if there is none, generated it and store it in the session
        if (!$seed) {
            $seed = time(); //can replace with custom logic if you want
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setListSeed($seed);
        }
        //get a random number based on seed
        srand($seed);
        $rand = rand(0, 100);
        //pass the random number to the sorting.
        $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('rand('.$rand.')');
    }
    else{
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
}
else {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
}
```